# Best way to eliminate all intermediate files from Visual Studio project folders?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm one of those people who rather dislike it when random non-source files are dropped by the IDE into my source directory. Especially if these are generated as part of the build.

I've found that by overriding both "<IntermediateOutputPath>" and "<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>" I can strip down the mess left behind to just a couple of empty directories, which I suppose I can tolerate.

However using "<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>" causes Visual Studio to ask whether I really want to open the project because it thinks this is an "unsafe" addition.

Does anyone know how to disable this safety check, or perhaps a way to get rid of all intermediate files without using "<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>"?

Comment: You might get more answers if you specified what files you mean, as I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I mean all the files under MyProject/bin/* and MyProject/obj/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried writing a macro in the post-build event for your project.  You should be able to execute

```
DEL -S -Q MyProject/bin/*.*
DEL -S -Q MyProject/obj/*.*
```

Hope this helps,

Bill

Comment: This is unfortunately only a half-fix - for some reason VS now decided that it needs to create an empty "bin" directory at various nesting levels in the folder hierarchy. Sigh....

What I ended up doing is just write a python script that wipes all bin & obj directories starting at current directory. Not a fix for everyone, but works for me.